# it deletes the value but after deleting the value the total get double and have to go out from activity to get refresh the amount after delete

Tags: android

Please help me out: the program deletes the value, but instead of deleting it's getting doubled, then I have to go out from activity to refresh the right amount after cacellation.

```
   DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sales");
    sum = 0;
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<SaleClass>();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                SaleClass p = (SaleClass) dataSnapshot1.getValue(SaleClass.class);

                list.add(p);
                sum += p.amount;




            }
            adapter = new SalesAdapter(Sales.this, list);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            ttv.setText(("Total Sale: " + sum));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Sales.this, "Opsss.... Something is wrong " + databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

upper code is to show values and

Adapter:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to DELETE?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
        return true;
    }
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Toast.makeText(context, getAdapterPosition()+" is clicked "+Sales.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sales").child(Sales.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    reference.removeValue();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

}
 this is for deleting the data and send it to main activity

Comment: It seems you are just removing the data from the database and not updating the array in the adapter. You need to remove the deleted reference in the array in the adapter first. Then you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` AFTER the item in the array has been removed.

Comment: i have tried to put notifyDataSetChanged() but nothing happens! is there any possible solution ? @DavidVelasquez, where exactly should i place the notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: Were you able to delete the item in the array that is used in your RecyclerView `adapter`?

Comment: yes in adapter, but thanks i already got the answer! the problem was simple all i did is sum=0; before (list = new ArrayList<SaleClass>(); ) so my problem get solved thanks :)